# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxx/music/ads/AudioAdManager for Inner project class

Tags: java, android

I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError of a class that is part of my Android project not a third-party library. 
This is the error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxx/music/ads/AudioAdManager.......
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.music.ads.AudioAdManager"
```

The **AudioAdManager** method was called from `com.xxx.music.player.PlayerService.triggerSomthing()`

```
public class AudioAdManager{
    static AudioAdManager instance;

    public AudioAdManager(){

    }

    public void doSomething(){
        ///
    }

    public static AudioAdManager getInstance(){
        if( instance == null){
            instance = new AudioAdManager();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}



public class PlaybackService{
    static PlaybackService instance;

    public PlaybackService(){

    }

    public void triggerSomthing(){
        /// do some other tasks 
        AudioAdManager.getInstance().doSomething();
    }

    public static PlaybackService getInstance(){
        if( instance == null){
            instance = new PlaybackService();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

This is my app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug{
            multiDexKeepFile file("multidex.txt")
            multiDexKeepProguard file("multidex.keep")
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexKeepFile file("multidex.txt")
            multiDexKeepProguard file("multidex.keep")
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental false
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    sourceSets{
        main{
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'

    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString()
    }
}
```

I have tried the following guides and none of them seems to be working: When i try to open `app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/maindexlist.txt`, the same class is listed there.

1. the guide given here [multidex from developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep)
2. [Article on medium](https://medium.com/groupon-eng/android-s-multidex-slows-down-app-startup-d9f10b46770f#.uvhmg7sw4)
3. Example1 project on github https://github.com/frogermcs/HelloMultidex
4. Example2 project on https://github.com/mmadev/multidex-sample

Does anyone have a work around for this? I will really appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are typo's in your classes' definitions: "class" appears two times.

```
public class class AudioAdManager
public class class PlaybackService
```

Besides this (now fixed) issue, can you explain how you are calling your triggerSomthing() method ? Is it called on a PlaybackService object, or are you trying to call it statically ?

Comment: It shouldn't compile.

Comment: @MutindaBoniface - I edited my answer. Could you also provide the full stack trace ?

Comment: Am not calling from a static context. Check this line 
```public void triggerSomthing(){
     /// do some other tasks 
     AudioAdManager.getInstance().doSomething();
 }

Comment: Ok. There's just one thing still bothering me: you provided some details on the PlaybackService class, while you're saying that:
"The AudioAdManager method was called from com.xxx.music.player.PlayerService.triggerSomthing()"

Can you explain a bit more the package structure ?
From what I see, you have a com.xxx.music.ads package, in which the AudioAdManager class is located ; and you have a com.xxx.music.player package in which you have your PlayerService class.